# TypeScript and Union Types

Tags: typescript

Given: Reducer accepts one of the four actions:

```
interface ItemAction {
    type: 'ADD_TODO'|'DELETE_TODO'|'TOGGLE_TODO',
    id: number
}

interface QueryAction {
    type: 'SET_QUERY',
    query: string
}
```

I expect the code of the reducer contain something like:

```
if (action as ItemAction) {
   console.log(action.id); // typescript knows that "id" is available here
} else {
   console.log(action.query); // typescript knows that action is of type QueryAction and hence "query" is available here
}
```

How do I achieve that with TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

```
let action: ItemAction | QueryAction = ...;
if ('id' in action) {
  // Type inferred as ItemAction
} else {
  // Type inferred as QueryAction
}
```

For more complex cases, you can use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).

Comment: This answer is quite right.  I do prefer type guards in most cases because if you change the form of the object later on, you only have to edit your "checking" code in one place--the type guard--rather than finding the various places you used `in`.  But that is entirely a matter of preference and the particulars of your code base.

Answer (score 1):

This can be handled with a user-defined typeguard.  For example

```
function isItemAction(someAction: any): someAction is ItemAction {
  if(someAction.id !== undefined and typeof someAction.id === 'number') {
    return true
  } else return false
}

if (if isItemAction(action)) {
  console.log(action.id); // typescript knows that "id" is available here
}
```

A few things to know about typeguards: (1) they require the use of the type predicate "is" language; (2) they are conventionally named as I have named them, isX; (3) TS has no way of knowing that the evaluation logic in your function is accurate, that's up to you, in other words, a typeguard that always evaluates to true will be fine from TS's perspective.

See [here](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/typeguard#user-defined-type-guards) for more info on writing user defined type guards.